# node-gyp build error on mac for npm install - Error: `make` failed with exit code

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, node-sass

I have a Vue.js app and I am trying to setup it in my local Mac machine. But when I use `npm install` to install the dependanceis, I am getting the following error

```
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/username/Desktop/Work/Projects/project_name/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/username/Desktop/Work/Projects/project_name/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/username/Desktop/Work/Projects/project_name/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

At first it was showing an error that says `python2` was not found. Now I have installed and switched to Python2 and now this error is coming. I have tried almost everything but still the issue is not fixed. Please find my environment details below:

- OS - MacOS Monterey
- Node - 16.0.0
- npm - 7.10.0
- Python  - 2.7.18

and my package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "my-app-client",
  "dependencies": {
    "@gtm-support/vue2-gtm": "^1.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "cryptr": "^4.0.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.5.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.17.1",
    "vue-session": "^1.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "less": "^3.0.1",
    "less-loader": "~4.1.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.15.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

This is a legacy codebase and sometimes, the package versions were too old. IS there any work around to fix this issue and so I can run the application on local ?

Comment: Try Node14 and see if you can update Node-Sass to 4.14+ (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using nodejs 16.x. try to install sass instead of node-sass.

```
npm uninstall node-sass
```

```
npm install sass --save
```