# yarn install Dockerfile gives message: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Tags: docker, dockerfile, yarnpkg

When try to execute my frontend project (react-vite) that works in my local machine , with yarn in Docker , Its a really long confusing message

I try running yarn install with others args but nothing works
Could not find anything related with my error

Any ideas ?
My dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

The error

```
....
v8::Isolate::IdleNotificationDeadline(double)' is deprecated: Use MemoryPressureNotification() to influence the GC schedule. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
139.0   686 |     return v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()->IdleNotificationDeadline(
139.0       |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
139.0   687 |         idle_time_in_ms * 0.001);
139.0       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                               
139.0 In file included from /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/v8-initialization.h:13,
139.0                  from /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/v8.h:34,
139.0                  from /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/node.h:73,
139.0                  from ../../nan/nan.h:60:
139.0 /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/v8-isolate.h:1341:8: note: declared here
139.0  1341 |   bool IdleNotificationDeadline(double deadline_in_seconds);
139.0       |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
139.0 ../src/binding.cpp: In function 'Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)':
139.0 ../src/binding.cpp:284:80: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'void (*)(uv_work_t*)' {aka 'void (*)(uv_work_s*)'} to 'uv_after_work_cb' {aka 'void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)'} [-Wcast-function-type]
139.0   284 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
139.0       |                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
139.0 ../src/binding.cpp: In function 'Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render_file(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)':
139.0 ../src/binding.cpp:320:80: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'void (*)(uv_work_t*)' {aka 'void (*)(uv_work_s*)'} to 'uv_after_work_cb' {aka 'void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)'} [-Wcast-function-type]
139.0   320 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
139.0       |                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
139.0 ../src/binding.cpp: At global scope:
139.0 /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/node.h:1172:7: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)' {aka 'void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)'} to 'node::addon_register_func' {aka 'void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)'} [-Wcast-function-type]
139.0  1172 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
139.0       |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
139.0 /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/node.h:1206:3: note: in expansion of macro 'NODE_MODULE_X'
139.0  1206 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
139.0       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
139.0 ../src/binding.cpp:358:1: note: in expansion of macro 'NODE_MODULE'
139.0   358 | NODE_MODULE(binding, RegisterModule);
139.0       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
139.0 In file included from /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:12,
139.0                  from /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/v8.h:24:
139.0 /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/v8-local-handle.h: In instantiation of 'v8::Local<T>::Local(v8::Local<S>) [with S = v8::Data; T = v8::Value]':
139.0 ../../nan/nan_callbacks_12_inl.h:175:53:   required from here
139.0 /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/v8-local-handle.h:253:42: error: static assertion failed: type check
139.0   253 |     static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, S>::value, "type check");
139.0       |                                          ^~~~~
139.0 /root/.cache/node-gyp/21.2.0/include/node/v8-local-handle.h:253:42: note: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' evaluates to false
139.0 make: *** [binding.target.mk:131: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
139.0 make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass/build'
139.0 gyp ERR! build error 
139.0 gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
139.0 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
139.0 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
139.0 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
139.0 gyp ERR! System Linux 6.2.0-36-generic
139.0 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
139.0 gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass
139.0 gyp ERR! node -v v21.2.0
139.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
139.0 gyp ERR! not ok 
139.0 Build failed with error code: 1
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
pedro@feijoesCompu:~/Desktop/die
```

Comment: Try:  with `FROM node:21-alpine` and add `RUN apk add --nocache python make g++`

Comment: Same error ```
151.3 gyp ERR! build error 

151.3 gyp ERR! node -v v21.2.0151.3 gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
151.3 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
151.3 gyp ERR! System Linux 6.2.0-37-generic
151.3 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
151.3 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
151.3 gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: can you add `RUN yarn global add node-gyp` just before `RUN yarn` ?

Comment: same error 234.4 gyp ERR! System Linux 6.2.0-37-generic
234.4 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
234.4 gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass
234.4 gyp ERR! node -v v21.2.0
234.4 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
234.4 gyp ERR! not ok 
234.4 Build failed with error code: 1

Comment: Are-you on MacOS ?  Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361504/npm-install-not-working-for-node-v-16-0-0 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73884256/node-gyp-build-error-on-mac-for-npm-install-error-make-failed-with-exit-cod